# Struts make a link with wildcard parameter

Tags: java, struts, wildcard, struts-1, url-parameters

So say I have the following action mapping:

```xml
<action path="/admin/nst-*/manage/"
    type="com.company.backend.actions.admin.nstManageAction"
    name="nstMgmtForm" attribute="form"
    validate="false" scope="request"
    parameter="{1}"
    input="/WEB-INF/company/pages/nstMgmt.jsp">
    <forward name="view" path="/WEB-INF/company/pages/nstMgmt.jsp"/>
</action>
```

As you can see, it has a wildcard for institution which is passed in with the parameter attribute.

Say on another JSP page I wanted to link to this action with a Struts `html` tag.  How would I automatically insert the institution `id` into the the link with the Struts link tag?  For instance `/admin/nst-22/manage/`  or `/admin/nst-99/manage`.  Is it possible to do this with the the link tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use EL expression in the action attribute

```
<html:link action="/admin/nst-${id}/manage/">Manage</html:link>
```

Struts1 tag attributes accept EL expressions, so it's possible.